# Android get quaternion data

Tags: android, android-sensors, quaternions

Fast and simple. How to get the quaternion data from the sensors?
basically I need:

```
float quaternion_x = ?
float quaternion_y = ?
float quaternion_z = ?
float quaternion_w = ?
```

I have something like this:

```
if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR)
{
    float[] values = event.values;

    float quaternion_x = values[0];
    float quaternion_y = values[1];
    float quaternion_z = values[2];
    float quaternion_w = values[3];  <----- ERROR HERE 
}
```

I get an index out of bound exception because values has only 3 values inside. According to this page:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html
There should be 4 values or am I understanding something wrong?

Comment: `How to get the quaternion data from the sensors?` Definition of [quaternion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion)

Comment: Nobody is `reinventing the wheel`. A **quaternion** is simply **something else**. It refers to **fractals**, and has nothing to do with your question. And **no**, as stated [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-rotate), you only expect 3 values (x, y, z). Feel free to call it **TERNION**, if you like... ;)

Comment: So there is no possibility to get "what I want" from the code above? According to the definition of `TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR` the result should be: `The three elements of the rotation vector are equal to the last three components of a unit quaternion` so basically the x,y,z or still wrong? :(

Comment: `The three elements of the rotation vector are expressed as follows: 
x*sin(θ/2) 
y*sin(θ/2) 
z*sin(θ/2)
` so, there's no **w**. Set it to 0, if you like. I'd initialize the array with all 0s (or any other value you see fit, i.e.: -1) first, then try to fill it with the read values. So, at least you'll have `w = 0`

Comment: Actually, in the documentation, it says "`values[3]`, originally optional, will always be present from SDK Level 18 onwards". `values[3]` in this case is cos(&theta/2) [source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `SensorManager` class offers a helper function to convert for you:

```
SensorManager.getQuaternionFromVector(Q, values);
float[] quaternion_w = Q[0];
float[] quaternion_x = Q[1];
float[] quaternion_y = Q[2];
float[] quaternion_z = Q[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

The android implementation of **getOrientation** returns the same values of ***getQuaterionFromVector***.
So, you can take those values and construct the Quaternion if you want;

```
float[] quaternion = new float[4];
quaternion[0] = 0;  //w
quaternion[1] = orientation[0];  //x
quaternion[2] = orientation[1];  //y
quaternion[3] = orientation[2];  //z
```

I checked it out with this code.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
        mMagneticField = event.values;
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        mGravity = event.values;
    if ((mGravity == null) || (mMagneticField == null))
        return;

    float R[] = new float[9];
    float I[] = new float[9];
    boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity, mMagneticField);
    if (success) {
        mOrientation = new float[3];
        mQuaternion = new float[4];
        SensorManager.getOrientation(R, mOrientation);
        mAzimut = mOrientation[0]; // orientation contains: azimut, pitch and roll
        mPitch = mOrientation[1];
        mRoll = mOrientation[2];

        SensorManager.getQuaternionFromVector(mQuaternion, mOrientation);

        if(mAzimut - mQuaternion[1] == 0 && mPitch - mQuaternion[2] == 0 && mRoll - mQuaternion[3] == 0){
            Log.d("ORIENTATION", "QUATERNION IS THE SAME");
        }
        notifyObservers();
    }
}
```